# Custom DataGridViewColumn - Cell is not being painted (visible) until mouse double click

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I need to build a custom DataGridViewColumn for a datagridview so... imagine the following scenario (skeleton):

```
public class CustomColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
        public CustomColumn(PropertyEditor propertyEditor)
            : base(new CustomCell(propertyEditor))
        {            
        }

        (...)
}

class CustomCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
        public PropertyEditor propertyEditor = null;

        public CustomCell() : base()
        {                
        }

        public CustomCell(PropertyEditor propertyEditor)
            : this()
        {                
            this.propertyEditor = propertyEditor;
        }

        (...)

        public override object DefaultNewRowValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.propertyEditor.Source;
            }
        }          

        (...) 
}

class CustomEditingControl : PropertyEditor, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
        (...)
}
```

*PropertyEditor is a National Instruments component. This is the content of the cell.

so I create a column programmatically and then add:

```
PropertyEditor propertyEditor = new PropertyEditor();
propertyEditor.Source = new PropertyEditorSource(new ScatterPlot(), "LineStep");
propertyEditor.SourceValue = "XYStep"; // Default value for property LineStep

PropertyEditorColumn col = new PropertyEditorColumn(propertyEditor);
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

My problem is that in DefaultNewRowValue, this.propertyEditor is null and not that passed by parameter because CustomCell constructor without arguments is called automatically after adding the column. I want to initialise the cell with a default value, with that passed as parameter. How can I achieve this?

Thx.

Comment: I have solved by overriding clone method in CustomCell and adding the propertyEditor to the new cell cloned.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Please add an answer and accept it, so it doesn't show up as an unanswered question. Also, it might help other people with the same problem.